# Char to Operator C++

Tags: c++, char, operators

Hey I wanted to know how you could turn a character '+' into an operator. For example if I had

```
char op = '+'
cout << 6 op 1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: With a map, `cout << operators[op](6, 1);`

Comment: If you want to keep the `6 op 1` syntax, then no, it's not possible.

Comment: Think about compiled instructions and runtime data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SImple way is to use a switch statement

```
switch (op)
{
case '+':
  res = x + y;
  break;
case '-':
  res = x - y;
  break;
case '*':
  res = x * y;
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a way as you've written it there but you could do something hacky like

```
int do_op(char op, int a, int b)
{
    switch(op)
    {
    case '+':
       return a+b;
    break;
    case '-':
       return a-b;
    break;
    case '*':
       return a*b;
    break;
    case '/':
       return a/b;
    break;
    default:
        throw std::runtime_error("unknown op")
    }
 }
```

Comment: valid suggestion, bu this is far from hacky.

Comment: Well no, but I feel it doesn't really get to the root of OPs question.

Comment: Yea I figured switches would be the way to go but thought there may of been a easier way.

Comment: You might also be able to do something with custom stream classes but that would get messy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an old-way #define:

```
#define op +
std::cout << 6 op 1;
```

However it has limited use.

If you want to do this in pure C++, you will have to use switch syntax either explicitely or in an external library (like tetzfamily.com/temp/EvalDoc.htm or codeproject.com/Articles/7939/C-based-Expression-Evaluation-Library)).

Another way is to use an external program, like bc:

```
char op = '+';
std::string s;
s += "6";
s += op;
s += "4";
system(("echo " + s + "|bc").c_str());
```

If you want to use the result later, check the [popen](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/28982/) function or the [C++ equivalent](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArithmeticOps {

   static int testcase11 = 11;
   static int testcase12 = 3;
   static char testcase13 = '/';

   public static void main(String args[]){
        ArithmeticOps testInstance = new ArithmeticOps();
        int result = testInstance.compute(testcase11,testcase12,testcase13);
        System.out.println(result);
   } 


public int compute(int a, int b,char operator){
    int i=0;
    switch(operator)
    {

    case '+' :
        i= a+b;
        break;
    case '-' :
        i= a-b;
        break;
    case '*' :
        i= a*b;
        break;
    case '/' :
        i= a/b;
        break;
    case '%' :
        i= a%b;
        break;
    case '^' :
        i= a^b;
        break;
    default:
        i=0;
    }
    return i;


}
```

}

Comment: this covers all arithmetic operations.